# Inno Setup Trying to create a new Install DirectX Template Product for Modular InnoSetup Dependency Installer

Tags: inno-setup, pascal

I am uing Modular Inno Setup

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20868/NET-Framework-1-1-2-0-3-5-Installer-for-InnoSetup#xx3672600xx

I am modifying an existing DirectX Detector method

http://www.vincenzo.net/isxkb/index.php?title=DirectX_-_How_to_detect_DirectX_version

I am trying to create a new product to install DirectX 9

Here is what I have so far.

```
//========================================
//detectDirectX.iss
//=======================================


[CustomMessages]
directx_title=DirectX End-User Runtimes (June 2010)

en.directx_size=95.6 MB
de.directx_size=95.6 MB

[Code]
const
    directx_url = 'http://download.microsoft.com/download/8/4/A/84A35BF1-DAFE-4AE8-82AF-AD2AE20B6B14/directx_Jun2010_redist.exe';


procedure DecodeVersion( verstr: String; var verint: array of Integer );
var
  i,p: Integer; s: string;
begin
  // initialize array
  verint := [0,0,0,0];
  i := 0;
  while ( (Length(verstr) > 0) and (i < 4) ) do
  begin
    p := pos('.', verstr);
    if p > 0 then
    begin
      if p = 1 then s:= '0' else s:= Copy( verstr, 1, p - 1 );
      verint[i] := StrToInt(s);
      i := i + 1;
      verstr := Copy( verstr, p+1, Length(verstr));
    end
    else
    begin
      verint[i] := StrToInt( verstr );
      verstr := '';
    end;
  end;

end;

// This function compares version string
// return -1 if ver1 < ver2
// return  0 if ver1 = ver2
// return  1 if ver1 > ver2
function CompareVersion2( ver1, ver2: String ) : Integer;
var
  verint1, verint2: array of Integer;
  i: integer;
begin

  SetArrayLength( verint1, 4 );
  DecodeVersion( ver1, verint1 );

  SetArrayLength( verint2, 4 );
  DecodeVersion( ver2, verint2 );

  Result := 0; i := 0;
  while ( (Result = 0) and ( i < 4 ) ) do
  begin
    if verint1[i] > verint2[i] then
      Result := 1
    else
      if verint1[i] < verint2[i] then
        Result := -1
      else
        Result := 0;

    i := i + 1;
  end;

end;

// DirectX version is stored in registry as 4.majorversion.minorversion
// DirectX 8.0 is 4.8.0
// DirectX 8.1 is 4.8.1
// DirectX 9.0 is 4.9.0

function GetDirectXVersion(): String;
var
  sVersion:  String;
begin
  sVersion := '';

  RegQueryStringValue( HKLM, 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\DirectX', 'Version', sVersion );

  Result := sVersion;
end;

procedure directX();
var ErrorCode: Integer;
begin
  // in this case program needs at least directx 9.0
  if CompareVersion2( GetDirectXVersion(), '4.9.0') < 0 then
  begin
                AddProduct('directx_Jun2010_redist.exe',
                    '/t:' + ExpandConstant('{tmp}\DirectX') + ' /q /c',
                    CustomMessage('directx_title'),
                    CustomMessage('directx_size'),
                    directx_url,
                    false, false);

          //Is there any way to wait until directx_Jun2010_redist.exe has extracted it self before calling the next line? 
         ShellExec('open', ExpandConstant('{tmp}\DirectX\DXSETUP.exe'), '/silent', '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ErrorCode)
  end;
end;
```

In the main setup file whatever.iss under [RUN]

I included the file.

```
#include "scripts\products\custom\detectDirectX.iss"
```

In the main setup file whatever.iss under [CODE]

I included this method

```
directX();
```

The problem I am having is that it's downloading like it should and placing it in the Temp folder.

```
        AddProduct('directx_Jun2010_redist.exe',
            '/t:' + ExpandConstant('{tmp}\DirectX') + ' /q /c',
            CustomMessage('directx_title'),
            CustomMessage('directx_size'),
            directx_url,
            false, false);
```

since I am using the extra pars

'/t:' + ExpandConstant('{tmp}\DirectX') + ' /q /c'

once it's downloaded it creating a folder called DirectX and Extracting everything into it.  which takes a bit.

It seems while directx_Jun2010_redist.exe is extracting..

```
ShellExec('open', ExpandConstant('{tmp}\DirectX\DXSETUP.exe'), '/silent', '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ErrorCode)
```

is getting called to early and the file {tmp}\DirectX\DXSETUP.exe does not exist yet.. so it does not get called.

Once extracting is finished, the user clicks finish on the installed and it delete the Temp folder.

Is there a way to fix this problem so that after directx_Jun2010_redist.exe has extracted it's files it can run DXSETUP.exe before the installer finishes?

Comment: When do you want to download and execute that DirectX setup ? At which stage ? Consider, that user might not be connected to the Internet...

Comment: 1.  It's a dependency.  2. Right after directx_Jun2010_redist.exe has finished extracting all the required files.  If the user is not connect to the internet then the installer should fail since the program it self requires internet.

Answer (score 2):

Ok I think I finally got it to working correctly..  I had to move things around a bit.. it seems some things get called at start up but do not actually fire they are qued until later.  With that In mind I was able to solve this problem.  Here is the code.

In your main setupfile.iss add the following under **[RUN]**

```
Filename: "{tmp}\DirectX\DXSETUP.exe"; WorkingDir: "{tmp}\DirectX"; Parameters: "/silent"; Check: checkDirectX; Flags: waituntilterminated;


#include "scripts\products\custom\detectDirectX.iss"
```

Also in your main setupfile.iss add the following under **[Code]**

```
directX();
```

Here is the code for detectDirectX.iss

```
[CustomMessages]
directx_title=DirectX End-User Runtimes (June 2010)

en.directx_size=95.6 MB
de.directx_size=95.6 MB

[Code]
const
    directx_url = 'http://download.microsoft.com/download/8/4/A/84A35BF1-DAFE-4AE8-82AF-AD2AE20B6B14/directx_Jun2010_redist.exe';


procedure DecodeVersion( verstr: String; var verint: array of Integer );
var
  i,p: Integer; s: string;
begin
  // initialize array
  verint := [0,0,0,0];
  i := 0;
  while ( (Length(verstr) > 0) and (i < 4) ) do
  begin
    p := pos('.', verstr);
    if p > 0 then
    begin
      if p = 1 then s:= '0' else s:= Copy( verstr, 1, p - 1 );
      verint[i] := StrToInt(s);
      i := i + 1;
      verstr := Copy( verstr, p+1, Length(verstr));
    end
    else
    begin
      verint[i] := StrToInt( verstr );
      verstr := '';
    end;
  end;

end;

// This function compares version string
// return -1 if ver1 < ver2
// return  0 if ver1 = ver2
// return  1 if ver1 > ver2
function CompareDirectXVersion( ver1, ver2: String ) : Integer;
var
  verint1, verint2: array of Integer;
  i: integer;
begin

  SetArrayLength( verint1, 4 );
  DecodeVersion( ver1, verint1 );

  SetArrayLength( verint2, 4 );
  DecodeVersion( ver2, verint2 );

  Result := 0; i := 0;
  while ( (Result = 0) and ( i < 4 ) ) do
  begin
    if verint1[i] > verint2[i] then
      Result := 1
    else
      if verint1[i] < verint2[i] then
        Result := -1
      else
        Result := 0;

    i := i + 1;
  end;

end;

// DirectX version is stored in registry as 4.majorversion.minorversion
// DirectX 8.0 is 4.8.0
// DirectX 8.1 is 4.8.1
// DirectX 9.0 is 4.9.0

function GetDirectXVersion(): String;
var
  sVersion:  String;
begin
  sVersion := '';

  RegQueryStringValue( HKLM, 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\DirectX', 'Version', sVersion );

  Result := sVersion;
end;


function checkDirectX(): boolean;
begin
  // in this case program needs at least directx 9.0
  if CompareDirectXVersion( GetDirectXVersion(), '4.9.0') < 0 then
  begin
       Result := true;
  end
  else
  begin
    Result := false;
   end;

end;



procedure directX();
begin
  // in this case program needs at least directx 9.0
  if CompareDirectXVersion( GetDirectXVersion(), '4.9.0') < 0 then
  begin
                AddProduct('directx_Jun2010_redist.exe',
                    '/t:' + ExpandConstant('{tmp}\DirectX') + ' /q /c',
                    CustomMessage('directx_title'),
                    CustomMessage('directx_size'),
                    directx_url,
                    false, false);

  end;
end;
```

I hope this helps someone else.. The Entire Idea is that I could ship my software and not worry about DirectX, at a minimum my software needed DirectX 9 some XP users may not have updated their machines.. Or some may have deleted it on vista or 7, Windows 8 ships out of the box with a newer version so no worries there.

Comment: I was looking for something like this. After some time, did you have a good experience with it? (wondering that putting in the installer a dependency on an URL from MS is a good idea in the long term)